# Sub-Optimal exercise

Tags: options, american, embedded-options

I have seen exercise multiples applied to account for sub-optimal exercise of American style options in the case of employee share schemes (as the employees are irrational). I would like to know if there is any market practice of applying such multiples in the case of certain corporate options, such as convertible bonds or protective put options embedded in private equity purchases.